# How to create a Cassandra ITrigger destructor?

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, apache-kafka, triggers

I am sending data from Cassandra to Kafka using a trigger jar that implements the ITrigger interface.

To make sure that I only try to send messages to Kafka when some servers are available (to avoid the timeout overhead) - I am spawning a new thread that tries to connect to Kafka at a set frequency and updates a boolean in case of a status change.

In my constructor of the Cassandra Trigger, I am spawning a new thread for this Kafka checker.

```
        // Start the background thread to monitor apache health
         b_array = cr.get_broker_array();
         bt = new background_thread(b_array, ms, lLog);
         bt.start();
```

My problem is, I don't have any event that can let me know when the main trigger has been reloaded.

If the trigger gets reloaded with

`./nodetool reloadtriggers`

The old thread keeps running in the background and does not get cleaned. I have seen references that using `finalize()` is a bad idea and should not be done.

Currently the only way to refresh the trigger is actually restarting the Cassandra node - which is just wrong.

Any inputs on how this can be approached or accomplished would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve the issue.

- Tracked the time of the last message received on the background thread.
- If a new message did not arrive for 15 minutes I would slow down the kafka health-check by 30 seconds on every loop.
- If a new message did not come in for 4 hours. I would exit the health-check loop. Every time the trigger is reloaded a new instance of the trigger is launched and a new thread is launched. **The older instances of triggers/threads don't get new messages. So the timeout wait will kill the background zombie threads (which was my original problem).**
- When processing new messages I check if the state of the background thread was TERMINATED and started a new background thread if that was the case. (with write lock to make sure multiple threads are not launched by concurrent messages).